# CORS audio streaming (apache)

Tags: javascript, apache, cors

I am trying to implement a version of this audio visualiser on a website.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/540ptxka/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=540ptxka)

It all works fine except for when the audio being streamed is from another server, then CORS kicks in and stops playback.

Because I have control of the server where the audio is being streamed from, I have added:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
```

To the httpd.conf file.

Confusingly this has removed the warning in Firefox but the CORS message still comes up in Chrome and the audio is therefore not streamed. In Safari no message is displayed about CORS but the audio also does not stream.

The message from Chrome is:

```
Access to audio at 'http://example.com/file.mp3' from origin 
'http://fiddle.jshell.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This clearly is not a bug in Chrome or Safari as both browsers play the default audio used in the JS Fiddle example, which is on another server.

So that suggests the issue is with the Apache setup, but I have used a CORS tool and indeed the desired URL does show and having the policy of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"` as expected.

Now I am truly stuck! Why is Chrome not reading the CORS policy correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is also required in the httpd.conf file:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET"
```